# R bootstrap boot sampling leads to some predictors having only one value

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, bootstrap

The context is not very important but still, here it is: i am using the `boot` package to calculate bootstrap confidence interval for different statistics (coefficients of doubly robust method estimates, C-index, etc…) and I happen to face the same problem each time.

If I understood it correctly, the issue is that, no matter which statistic, I need to fit some glm model on each sample and at some point it throws a contrast error because some of the factors predictors in my model have only one level on this sample.

I can think of 3 solutions but either I don’t know how to code it easily or I don’t like it :

1. I can include some test in my statistic function to exclude a predictor with less than one value but this means that i’m not fitting the same model on each sample, which I don’t like…
2. I could just drop the samples where it happens (and I can increase the number of replicates - `R` parameter of `boot` function - to compensate the loss of replicates) but I can’t do it easily with `boot` function since the error breaks the run. I could use some `try` or `tryCatch` code inside my statistic function but I feel like there must be an easier way
3. I could use the `strata` parameter of `boot` function: at the moment, I only stratified the sampling on my dependant variable *y="event occured"* but I could use a new strata variable that would consist of crossing all categorical predictors so as to have one strata for each combination of factors’ levels. However, this may result in a very large number of stratas...

I hope someone might have some insights on this issue because I can’t find anything online.

Any idea, advice or comment will be much appreciated.

It is not trivial but if needed I'll try to build some reproducible example.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that one of your predictors is a categorical variable, and that variable has some level where only 1 individual has that level? Eg, for a City variable you have lots of City A and City B, but only 1 City C?

Comment: It is not that extreme but yes, proportions amongst levels can be quite unbalanced through the different categorical predictors. EDIT: eg, 14 'yes' vs 467 'no' for one predictor

Comment: "I need to fit some glm model on each sample" Maybe, bootstrap the residuals? (Also, using `tryCatch` is very easy but of course you can't really rely on the bootstrap result if too many resamples don't give a successful fit.)

Comment: I am probably not familiar enough with residual resampling but I still have to fit my model on each sample at some point, no ?

Comment: Yes, but it preserves the predictors. Only the values of the dependent variable are different between the resamples. Here is the algorithm: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/73985/11849

Comment: ok I think I got it, you fit the model indeed on each sample but you have the same individuals so no problem of dropping factor levels, predictors remain the same only the response Y get changed by the residual resampling, am I correct ? EDIT: oops, crossed comments

Comment: After some reading, I have a new question : how can I generalize the residual resampling approach to GLM model ? Or at least to logistic regression since my outcome is binary ?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/448311/11849

Comment: yes thanks, i saw that one, and also the topic linked in one of the comment, but I don't know how am i supposed to generate my new $y_i$. Should I just do for each observation $i$ a Bernouilli `rbinom` with probability $p=\frac{1}{1+e^{\sum{\beta_ix_i}}}$ ? i opened a new topic to try to sort my problem out [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584098/confidence-interval-for-c-index)

Comment: THANK YOU @Roland for your help. I edited the quesiton with the solution I eventually came up with

Comment: Please move that from the question to an answer so people can vote on it. Self-answering is encouraged here.

Comment: What are the frequencies of observed Y and what is the dimensionality of candidate predictors?  Need to make sure the data have sufficient information to do any of this.

Comment: I have around 7% of event occurrences in Y. There are 6 to 8 covariates in the different models (factor predictors have only 2 levels except one that has 3). Overall, I have around 1000 observations but there are between 250 and 450 observations according to the subsample of interest. That seemed ok to me but without any mathematical proof...

Answer (score 1):

Following @Roland's advice and after some research about how to generalize residuals resampling to GLM models, here is what i did in the end.

```r
# removing na
data_tmp <- df %>% 
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ !is.na(.)))

# fit the GLM model
mod1 <- glm(y ~ .,
            data = data_tmp %>% select(-ind1),
            family = "binomial")

mod2 <- glm(y ~ .,
            data = data_tmp,
            family = "binomial")


# Bootstrapping C-index
cind_boot_stat <- function(data, indices){
  # generate new y sample with Bernouilli each time
  d <- data %>% mutate(
    y1 = rbinom(nrow(data_tmp), 1, mod1$fitted.values),
y2 = rbinom(nrow(data_tmp), 1, mod2$fitted.values))
  
  # fitting the logistic and calculating C-index
  c1 <- DescTools::Cstat(glm(y1 ~ .,
                             data = d %>% select(-y, -ind1),
                             family = "binomial"))
  
  c2 <- DescTools::Cstat(glm(y2 ~ .,
                             data = d %>% select(-y),
                             family = "binomial"))
  
  return(c(c1, c2))
}

cind_boot <- boot::boot(data_tmp, cind_boot_stat, R = 1000)
```

Hopefully this is statistically right but at least it seems to work !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I've dealt with this issue before using `boot.ci` to create bootstrapped confidence intervals.

I've used code like the following.  As an example, here, the code returns the r-squared value for a linear model, labeled `STAT`.

```
library(boot)

Function = function(input, index){
                    Input = input[index,]

### CAN INSERT TEST OF APPROPRIATENESS HERE

                    Result = lm (Words.per.minute ~ Age + Age2,
                                          data = Input)
                    Stat = summary(Result)$r.squared
                    return(Stat)}

    
Boot = boot(Data,
             Function,
             R=5000)
            
mean(Boot$t[,1])
```

*Reference: here, with the caveat that I wrote it:* [rcompanion.org/handbook/G_10.html](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_10.html)

At the point where it says `### CAN INSERT TEST OF APPROPRIATENESS HERE` you can check to be sure that your predictor has at least two levels.  This would be in the data frame called `Input`.

If it doesn't, there are a couple of options. First is to exclude that iteration, and go on to to calculate the confidence interval.  Second is to return an `NA` or something for the confidence interval as a whole.

In either case, if you find that your predictor has only one level (or fewer levels than the original data frame), you would set `FLAG=1` and then make the next step `if(FLAG==0){` so that it doesn't fit the model in the next step if FLAG equals 1.

Hopefully that makes sense, and hopefully I'm actually answering (that part of) the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It matches my solution 2. I coded something similar with a `try` inside my bootstrap stat function. However, the problem remained because at some point, most of the samples in the bootstrap iteration had a predictor with only one level (due to unbalanced levels in the original sample and to a too small population). The bootstrap results then were a bit unreliable to me. This is why I liked the residuals resampling solution since the population (and hence the levels of different predictors) stays the same, only the response gets changed